# Решение строкового математического выражения

Tags: java, строки, package

Есть ли в java нативный метод для такого рода вещей, чтобы самому не писать?
Вроде

```
String expr = "1 + 2 * 3";
Double result = WonderClass.wonderMethod(expr);
System.out.println(result);
```

---

```
7.0
```

Comment: System.out.println(2+2*2)

Comment: @AndrewBystrov, -_- извините, некорректно поставил вопрос, исправил

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Да, можно использовать [Java Scripting API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/scripting/programmer_guide/)

Вполне подойдет JavaScript (его движок входит в состав JDK):

```
ScriptEngineManager scriptEngineManager = new ScriptEngineManager();
ScriptEngine engine = scriptEngineManager.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
String expr = "1 + 2 * 3";
System.out.println(engine.eval(expr));
```

Comment: Изящно! А я уж полез дерево делать для парсера, благодарю вас.

Comment: Забыл добавить, что результат вычисления можно получать в виде переменной - вставить переменную через `engine.put()` и после вычисления получить ее значение через `engine.get()`

Comment: Почему именно движок jS? Почему они решили встроить движок именно JS? Чем обычная java плоха?

Comment: Для Java нужен компилятор, а JS - это типичный скриптирующий язык. Разницу между интерпретатором и компилятором разве не улавливаете?